# Error during project compilation in QT

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I just installed qt5.5 using qt offline installer for Linux on Ubuntu 15.04 when i tried creating a sample program for Qt desktop application i got the following Errors.

```
error: cannot find -lGL
error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched  on google a lot but was not able to rectify the problem i had not inserted any code yet into the sample code which comes when we create a new project.

Comment: Install `libgl1-mesa-dev` library using `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: @Nejat Thanks Sir. it Worked